# Android fly-out menu layout and styling

Tags: android, listview, layout, styling, flyout

I'm trying to make a menu like [Prixing](http://cyrilmottier.com/media/2012/05/the-making-of-prixing-fly-in-app-menu-part-1/app_menu_large.png). I've already implemented the code, the only thing i needed to know who to make that look and feel to base my app upon, i.e, the content and formatting of the xml layout of the fly-out menu. Is that a custom Listview and adapter with different layouts (sections and items) or it's like a menu with customizable items?

Comment: check this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: have a look at this. https://github.com/search?q=android+sliding+menu&type=&ref=simplesearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)  suits your purpose.

Sample code :

```
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

Comment: Thank you for code, but i've already done that, all i wanted to know is what does the xml layout of the behind view has to create that look. Sorry if i didn't make my question clear.

Comment: You want the look and feel of the Sliding menu as in Prixing. Rite?
To achieve that you need to create your own layout with the look and feel as you want and pass it instead of R.layout.menu in the sample code.

Comment: Yeah :) i'm not going to use the exact look and feel, it's just to have a working base for my app, because i like what they did with it.

Comment: I would like to know the technical details, like if they used a custom Listview and adapter with different layouts (sections and items) or a menu with customizable items

Comment: For Example, in the Prixing app screenshot they have used TextViews and CUstom ListView with images. You can see how to make Custom ListView with images in the following link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/